# Tcl : alloc: invalid block (core dumped)

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, tcl

I compiled tcl 8.5.7 with thread enabled. 
I installed threads using the following command :
    ./configure --enable-threads --enable-64bit

I installed tclreadline2.1.0-25.mga5.x86_64.rpm using yum.

I am bringing up the Tclsh with my code,

```
$ tclsh
Setting [some path] as myTc home directory
INFO : ###BEGIN_BEGIN-- INIT_LOG --BEGIN_BEGIN###
........
INFO : Logs will be in [thisPath] 
INFO : Time taken for test INIT execution 0 : 0 : 0
NOTICE : ###END_END_END-- INIT --END_END_END###
TC> 
**alloc: invalid block: 0x1f9cb50: 0 0
Aborted (core dumped)**
```

I even tried the instructions provided in the link : http://wiki.tcl.tk/5632.
But its not working. I am getting tclreadline error.

```
# make
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/log/packages/tclreadline-2.1.0'
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/include -I/tmp/readline-install/include/readline    -g -O2 -MT tclreadline.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tclreadline.Tpo -c -o tclreadline.lo tclreadline.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I/usr/include -I/tmp/readline-install/include/readline -g -O2 -MT tclreadline.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tclreadline.Tpo -c tclreadline.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/tclreadline.o
tclreadline.c:27:34: error: readline/readline.h: No such file or directory
tclreadline.c:28:33: error: readline/history.h: No such file or directory
tclreadline.c: In function ‘TclReadlineCmd’:
tclreadline.c:223: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘Tcl_GetIndexFromObj’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/tclDecls.h:267: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
tclreadline.c:431: error: ‘rl_line_buffer’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tclreadline.c:431: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
tclreadline.c:431: error: for each function it appears in.)
tclreadline.c: In function ‘TclReadlineInitialize’:
tclreadline.c:596: error: ‘rl_readline_name’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tclreadline.c:598: error: ‘rl_special_prefixes’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tclreadline.c:611: error: ‘rl_basic_word_break_characters’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tclreadline.c:636: error: ‘rl_attempted_completion_function’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tclreadline.c:636: error: ‘CPPFunction’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tclreadline.c:636: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
tclreadline.c: In function ‘TclReadlineCompletion’:
tclreadline.c:662: error: ‘rl_completion_append_character’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tclreadline.c:665: error: ‘rl_line_buffer’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tclreadline.c:672: error: ‘rl_end’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tclreadline.c:673: error: ‘rl_point’ undeclared (first use in this function)
tclreadline.c:746: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
tclreadline.c: In function ‘TclReadlineKnownCommands’:
tclreadline.c:804: error: ‘rl_line_buffer’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make[1]: *** [tclreadline.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/log/packages/tclreadline-2.1.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
[root@localhost tclreadline-2.1.0]#
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: As Tcl is up to Tcl 8.5.17 on the 8.5 maintenance branch, you try again using the current version. Either 8.5.17 or 8.6.3.

Comment: i tried in 8.5.17 also. i am getting the same error.